# Random characters popping up

Tags: c++

When I debug my program, it outputs a random stream of characters when outputting the asterisked line.

```
int main ()
{
string inputPuzzle;
cout << "Enter a word or set of words: ";
getline(cin, inputPuzzle);
char* puzzle = new char[inputPuzzle.size()+1];
memcpy(puzzle, inputPuzzle.c_str(), inputPuzzle.size()+1);
puzzle[inputPuzzle.size()+1] = '';
int strikes = 0;
char userInput;
char* userSoln = new char[inputPuzzle.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < inputPuzzle.size(); i++)
{
    userSoln[i] = '-';
    if (puzzle[i] == ' ')
    {
        userSoln[i] = ' ';
    }
}
bool solved = false;
int numberOfLetters;
for (;;)
{
    numberOfLetters = 0;
    cin >> userInput;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputPuzzle.size(); i++)
    {
        if (userInput == puzzle[i])
        {
            numberOfLetters++;
            userSoln[i] = puzzle[i];
        }
    }
    if (numberOfLetters == 0)
    {
        cout << "There are no " << userInput << "'s\n" ;
        strikes++;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "There are " << numberOfLetters << " " << userInput << "'s\n";
    }
    if (userSoln == puzzle)
    {
        break;
    }
    if (strikes == 10)
    {
        break;
    }
    **cout << "PUZZLE: " << userSoln << "\n";**
    cout << "NUMBER OF STRIKES: " << strikes << "\n";
}
if (strikes == 10)
{
    cout << "Sorry, but you lost. The puzzle was: " << puzzle;
}
else
{
    cout << "Congratulations, you've solved the puzzle!!! YOU WIN!!!!!";
    }
}
```

I've tried clearing cin buffers, but nothing doing. I have all the necessary include files (string and iostream) too, so that isn't the issue, and i have the namespace std above the main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a valid character constant.

```
puzzle[inputPuzzle.size()+1] = '';
```

If you intended a terminating character, it should be

```
puzzle[inputPuzzle.size()+1] = '\0';
```

or just

```
puzzle[inputPuzzle.size()+1] = 0;
```

or you could replace *both these lines*

```
memcpy(puzzle, inputPuzzle.c_str(), inputPuzzle.size()+1);
puzzle[inputPuzzle.size()+1] = '';
```

with [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy)

```
strcpy(puzzle, inputPuzzle.c_str());
```

**Edit:**

You also need to put a terminating character at the end of `userSoln` before printing it.

```
userSoln[ inputPuzzle.size() ] = '\0';
```

Comment: I am still getting a random stream of characters at the end of asterisked line.

Answer (score 0):

```
puzzle[inputPuzzle.size()+1] = '';
```

should be

```
puzzle[inputPuzzle.size()+1] = '\0';
```

you were trying to add the null terminator to the end of the string to signify the end, but '' is not quite it.